# Ember - Cannot set property 'type' of null

Tags: ember.js, routes

I have a big problem with ember. If i navigate to somewhere, i get the error `Cannot set property 'type' of null` sometimes and the view will not be rendered. The Error is thrown in jQuery, not in Ember.

I have never set `something.type` in my Application. I dont know what the error could be. An Example of a Route + Controller + View (dont forget, its not happening every time.)

Routing: `this.route("channels", {path: "/channels/:only"});`

Route:

```
App.ChannelsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params) {
    var controller = this.controllerFor("channels");
    controller.set("only", params.only);

    if (!controller.get("hasContent")) {
      return controller.updateContent();
    }
  }
});
```

Controller:

```
App.ChannelsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({

  sortProperties: ["position"],
  sortAscending: true,

  hasContent: function() {
    return this.get("content").length > 0;
  }.property("@each"),

  channels_category: function() {
    return this.get("only");
  }.property("only"),

  filteredContent: function() {
    var filterType = "group";
    var filterID = 1;

    switch(this.get("only")) {
      case "primary": filterType = "group"; filterID = 1; break;
      case "secondary": filterType = "group"; filterID = 2; break;
      case "regional": filterType = "group"; filterID = 3; break;
      case "hd": filterType = "hd"; filterID = true; break;
      default: filterType = "group"; filterID = 1; break;
    }

    return this.filterProperty(filterType, filterID);
  }.property("@each", "only"),

  updateContent: function() {
    return $.getJSON(getAPIUrl("channels.json")).then(function(data){
      var channels = [];
      $.each(data.channels, function() {

        var channel = App.Channel.create({
          id: this.id,
          name: this.name,
          group: this.group,
          hd: this.hd,
          position: this.position,
          recordable: this.recordable
        });
        channels.pushObject(channel);
      });

      return channels;
    });
  }
});
```

Its happening in a lot of controllers. I hope somebody knows a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you test this variation of your updateContent function?  changed the channels var to the controllers model...

```
  updateContent: function() {
    return $.getJSON(getAPIUrl("channels.json")).then(function(data){
      var channels = this.get('model');
      $.each(data.channels, function() {

        var channel = App.Channel.create({
          id: this.id,
          name: this.name,
          group: this.group,
          hd: this.hd,
          position: this.position,
          recordable: this.recordable
        });
        channels.pushObject(channel);
      });
    });
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, yes i will test it on monday and give u feedback than! ;)

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late answer. I tried it out and if i change the route, its working. But if i reload the page on this route, the application stucks in the loadingroute forever. The Console output is empty. I think the Loading Route expects any content to get returned after. Im not sure. *EDIT:* If i add `return [];` at the end of updateContent, its loading again, but the content is empty of course.

Answer (score 0):

If it's happening in jQuery, it's occurring either in an AJAX call or some DOM manipulation you're doing with jQuery. Your best start will be to have a fiddle with your AJAX calls, and check any Handlebars helpers you're using (especially if you have any [input helpers](http://emberjs.com/guides/views/built-in-views/) with types declared).

Comment: Okey good to know, i will create a little application to see if it is happening also there. i will try it on monday!